# Are WebTrends query Dimensions & Measures fixed for a report?

Tags: analytics

In viewing a report in WebTrends, I am limited to one dimension if I try to write a query.  When looking at the `Countries` report, I see the geographical data I want, but I also want to look at what `OS/Platform`'s are by country.  Is there no way to add more Dimensions & Measures?  Currently it auto-populates with only `Visits` showing.  I don't see an intuitive way to do this query with the way things currently look in this report.  Do I have to create another report?

Comment: If you elect to seek support at the [WebTrends forum](http://forums.webtrends.com/webtrends) or through [WebTrends support](http://webtrends.com/support/contact-support/) please consider posting any answer you receive.

Comment: I will let you know.  I did find out that to create custom reports you have to have some level of administrative privileges, but it's more than just the **Report Creation** option, which appears to just let you pick which dashboards go in views, and which reports.  Including data from dimensions not in reports already, looks to require something different.

Comment: As I found out, we currently have the Standard version, which doesn't include Custom Reports.  Hopefully when we upgrade, we go to the Advanced version.  Most of what is needed for basic analysis is in the preconfigured "Complete View", but if you want to start looking two dimensions together (like iPhone visitors by country) you need that ability to create [Custom Reports](http://s3.amazonaws.com/satisfaction-production/s3_images/680749/screenshot_inline.gif).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the Advanced Analysis version to do custom reports.  In addition you need to have the administrator enable the privileges for you to do it.  If you have the proper permissions checked (Custom Reports in Advanced), you should see the menu options below.  If you have the Standard Analysis version, you will see the Report Configuration options but not the Custom Reports.

[image]